# How to make a fetch request with custom herokuapp proxy?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm trying to make a fetch request with custom herokuapp proxy to an API, but when I do that it gives an error. Error says "There is no Target-Endpoint header in the request". Here is my code.

```
var userTargetUrl = `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=${steamApiKey}&vanityurl=${url}`

const response = await fetch(proxyUrl + userTargetUrl, {
    headers: {
        'Target-Endpoint': 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?'
    }
})
const data = await response.json()

url = data['response']['steamid']
```

I'm following their [instructions](https://elements.heroku.com/buttons/tobiasr/cors-proxy), but I couldn't figure it how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I won't pretend to be entirely sure, but maybe you can try

```
const response = await fetch(proxyUrl, {
    headers: {
        "Target-Endpoint": userTargetUrl
    }
});
```